# Flash Message pop up without redirect

Tags: python, search, flask, crud

I am trying to find a way to get Flask flashed messages to pop up without having to redirect the page. Basically if you enter some matching mnemonic pattern, it will search the database and display it in an alert below the search bar.

I've tried removing the redirect completely but that makes it not functional.

The javascript which brings the user to the URL:

```
function search() {
  var searchString = $("#inputSearch").val();

if (searchString.length == 4 && searchString.match(mnemonicPattern)) {
  $.get("search/" + searchString, function () {
    goToURL("search/"+searchString);
    labCatalog.search(searchString, true, false).draw();
  });
}
else if (searchString.length >= 6 && searchString.match(oracleNumberPattern)) {
  $.get("search/" + searchString, function (data) {
    goToURL("search/"+searchString);
    labCatalog.search(searchString, true, false).draw();
  });
}
else {
  labCatalog.search(searchString).draw();
}
```

}

The search function that fetches the data from database:

```
@app.route('/search/<string:id_data>',methods=['GET'])
def search(id_data):
        cur = mysql.connection.cursor()
        cur.execute("SELECT * FROM sims WHERE mnemonic=%s", [id_data])
        result = cur.fetchall()
        cur.close()
        for match in result:
                message = "Mnemonic: " + str([match[0]]) + ' Description: 
               + str([match[1]]) + ' RFT Date: ' + str([match[2]])
                flash(message)      
        return redirect(url_for('Index'))
```

I just want the flash message to pop up without having to redirect with localhost/search/mnemonicpattern.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need two changes - one in client side to display the alert box and one in server side to return the data.

1) In client side change

```
goToURL("search/"+searchString);
```

to

```
alert(data)
```

2) In server side change

```
message = "Mnemonic: " + str([match[0]]) + ' Description: 
           + str([match[1]]) + ' RFT Date: ' + str([match[2]])
            flash(message)      
    return redirect(url_for('Index'))
```

to

```
message = "Mnemonic: " + str([match[0]]) + ' Description: '
           + str([match[1]]) + ' RFT Date: ' + str([match[2]])    
    return message
```

If there are more than one matches in result , the changes above will ONLY send the last match. You may need to use 'message +=" instead of "message =" if you want to combine all the matches in one string to send to client to display in the alert

Comment: by data in alert, do you mean using the searchString variable?

Comment: no type in exact actual string "data" - since that's the variable name that holds the information that is being returned from the server - it comes from this line - $.get("search/" + searchString, function (data). The variable name xxx in function (xxx) must match the variable in the alert command - alert(xxx)

Comment: yup works perfectly, I was just missing function(data) in the first function. Thanks so much!